# issue in media scanner android

Tags: android, cordova, android-mediascanner

I have developed android phonegap app.I am recording the audio through phonegap api and to move the file i have created a plugin to start media scanner.But media scanner is starting to run after 7 or 8 seconds.So i cannot able to do other process in the app.Is there is any solution to find media scanner is completed or not in android.

Here is my code to start media scanner:

```
      sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Here is error in logcat:

```
 09-17 13:45:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(706): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 09-17 13:45:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(706): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.example/com.app.example.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 09-17 13:45:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
 09-17 13:45:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
 09-17 13:45:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
 09-17 13:45:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
 09-17 13:45:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 09-17 13:45:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 09-17 13:45:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
 09-17 13:45:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 09-17 13:45:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 09-17 13:45:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
 09-17 13:45:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
 09-17 13:45:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 09-17 13:45:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(706): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 09-17 13:45:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at android.content.ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(ContentResolver.java:804)
 09-17 13:45:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at com.app.mobilyzer.MobilyzerActivity.isMediaScannerScanning(MobilyzerActivity.java:79)
 09-17 13:45:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at com.app.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:72)
  09-17 13:45:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(706):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 09-17 13:45:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
 09-17 13:45:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(706):     ... 11 more
```

I need to show the progress bar until media scanner completed.Please kindly help me.Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to check if MediaScanner is running

```
 public static boolean isMediaScannerScanning(ContentResolver cr) {
        boolean result = false;
        Cursor cursor = query(cr, MediaStore.getMediaScannerUri(),
               new String [] {MediaStore.MEDIA_SCANNER_VOLUME},
                null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                result = "external".equals(cursor.getString(0));
            }
            cursor.close();
        }    
        return result;
    }
```

If you need a callback You could register for a content observer on `MediaStore.getMediaScannerUri()` . But when MediaScanner is going on you could receive too many changes on content observer.

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver( MediaStore.getMediaScannerUri(), false, contentobserver);
```

You will have to convert this to Phonegap code i guess.

Comment: Thanks nandeesh.whether i need to use this instead of sendBroadcast in my code.

Comment: no.. sendBroadcast is still to be done. This is to monitor the completion of media scanning that sendbroadcast would have started

Comment: I have used isMediaScannerScanning(cr) in the next line of sendBroadcast.But this method is called before media scanner started to run.

Comment: then use ContentResolver.registerContentObserver  and then check inside it

Comment: where to use this line.I am using isMediaScannerScanning(cr) in Activity class for sample.when i use this line code it is showing the error:'registerContentObserver cannot be resolved or is not a field '

Comment: I have used this line in oncreate below sendBroadcast,but my app force close and getting nullpointer exception.

Comment: can you edit your question to show the code and exception stack